# Converting pdf to string in objective c cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdftotext

I am working on a project where i am trying to read a locally stored pdf file and convert it to NSString.

I tried using this:

```
NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"pdfName"   ofType:@"pdf"];

NSData *pdfData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSError *error=nil;

NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:pdfData
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

However pdfData has content but when am converting to string, newStr gives me nil

Please help 
thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you be using the string for exactly? Do you hope the string has the text content from the PDF in it?

Comment: PDF isn't a text format so that code will never work.  Instead you need a library that actually understands the structure of PDF.

Comment: @Wain yes exactly..i want the string content from the pdf. NSData is stored as NSConcreteData

Comment: @trojanfoe Converting any views content to image is possible in cocoa but i wanted to know is there any way i can do this from image to text ? or something like converting pdf to text without using third party library

Comment: [PDF Document Parsing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-TPXREF101) or put the pdf in a PDFView and copy the text with [PDF Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001863-CH203-SW1)

Comment: @Willeke it gives html strings , so could not work